# Using mouse wheel scroll while dragging in react dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I have a specific web application where mouse wheel scrolling while dragging can save a lot of time. The code is written in React with React DnD (https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd) and HTML5 backend.

Unfortunately mouse wheel scrolling while dragging doesn't work as expected. I researched the problem and didn't find the universal solution. The issue is described here: https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/49. I also found the solution/hack that **works only on macOS** on all major browsers ([Google Chrome and drag to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829022/google-chrome-and-drag-to-scroll)). It doesn't work on Windows. I tried to hack it by changing position of the window on scroll event but it seems to be blocked.

Do you have any solution for that? Does writing custom backend could help? Unfortunately I haven't found any ready to use backend that could help.

Comment: I'd love to see a fix. You can try hacking JQuery UI into your app if you need it; scroll wheel works normally with its draggables.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in html spec, see the chrome issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=556169