# position: fixed , has a very bad performance on mobile/tablet devices when scrolling

Tags: css, performance, mobile, scroll, rasterizing

I'm using `position: fixed` in my site to fix the navigation bar in the view port, just like facebook's blue bar, but when we tried it on mobile/tablet devices (with their low processing powers) this fixed-bar makes a very bad hit on performance, which makes a very bad user experience when scrolling,

we used a very good articles to enhance the scrolling, and indeed they did, like:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/unnecessary-paints/
- https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-patterns/window-scroll-event.html

After a lot of modifications based on these articles, we reached to the point where `position: fixed` is the only investigation left for us to enhance in.

The site has an ultra-smooth scrolling when we change it to `position: absolute`. But with fixing it, the scrolling has a very bad drawback to the extent that it could hang the safari browser on ipad when scrolling in a certain way, **did you know how to use `position: fixed` with a good performance on tablet/mobile devices?**

Answer (score 7):

If your "tablet/mobile devices", which have performance problem, have a Webkit engine you probably could find answer here: [Chrome slow scrolling with fixed position elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969228/chrome-slow-scrolling-with-fixed-position-elements)

Fast answer: try to add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` on fixed block.

Comment: If you have a problem of footer (position:fixed) "following you" using -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); solves it (at least in Android < 2.2). THANKs!!!

Answer (score 7):

In order to get a smooth scrolling in mobile device, also when having "position: absolute",

you only need to add to the Div the css attribute

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

Comment: This does seem to improve performance quite a bit, though child elements with `position:fixed` seem to have very poor performance in mobile safari

Comment: This fixed my problem where I needed a div with `height: 100%` and `position: fixed`. Without that CSS scrolling was glitchy and with it I'm golden.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use "position: sticky"

Comment: What would be the performance difference between the 2?

Comment: Sticky is best... the motion is flawless... check this TABLE on mobile view: https://www.genevo.com/cz/srovnani-detektoru/  ... if you horizontally scroll it will stick the left columns