# HTML horizontal scrolling speed down on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have an HTML page with a horizontal scrolling. I'm using mac and bracket(ide) and it loads html page on chrome. 
the problem is scrolling speed is too high than i want for my webpage. so i tried to find proper code to add but i only could find things about vertical scrolling(top to down).

I tried to change the code i found to apply horizontal scrolling but It didn't work

this is my code :

```
body {
    font: 100% / 1.5 Arial;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;  
   }

<div class="parallax" style="vertical-align:top;"  >

<!-- some images are in here in division tags -->

</div>
```

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969228/chrome-slow-scrolling-with-fixed-position-elements

Comment: @IññoceñtÙšmâñ my problem is just opposite to your link ;-; i wanna make the scrolling speed down...